# how to hide / remove "<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4 Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->" while calling the wsdl link

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I have a wsdl file , where in there is a commented part i.e. `<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4 Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->` , which gets displayed whenever i make a call to wsdl link through browser. This is regarding web services in java with eclipse as an IDE.

I tried removing that part and validating but still it is showing. I just want that commented part not to be shown when a make call to wsdl link..need help

```
    wsdl file example:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://webservice.test.com" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://webservice.test.com" xmlns:intf="http://webservice.test.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    **<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
    Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->**
     <wsdl:types>
      <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://webservice.test.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <element name="checkDBConnection">
        <complexType/>
       </element>
       <element name="checkDBConnectionResponse">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="checkDBConnectionReturn" type="xsd:boolean"/>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>
      </schema>
     </wsdl:types>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Erm .... why do you need to do that?

Comment: its one kind of security issue for one of the client thats why

Comment: Really?  How can this possibly be a security issue?

Comment: cant say how this can be a security issue , but is there a way to hide it..please advise.

Comment: The possible security risk with having version is Attacker will get to know the vulnerable version of library application is using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any good reason to do this.  (And frankly the "security" reason is daft, IMO)

However, here are a couple of ideas.

1. Find / use a generic XML tool that strips comments.
2. Use an XSL transform to remove the comments; e.g. [XSL to completely remove comments (Including the space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446962/xsl-to-completely-remove-comments-including-the-space)
3. This Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/525974/how-to-remove-comments-from-an-xml-file explains how to do it using `sed`.
4. Download, modify and build your own copy of Apache Axis with the comment generation suppressed.

**UPDATE**

After rereading your question, I suspect you might be talking about the XML document that is returned in response to an `?wsdl` query.  If so, I think that option 4 might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify axis.jar:

1. Open axis.jar with archive tool (e.g. 7zip)
2. Navigate to \org\apache\axis\i18n\
3. Open resource.properties file in any text redactor (e.g. notepad++)
4. Change values to:

> ```
>   wsdlCreated00={0}
>
>   axisVersion=
>
>   axisVersionRaw=
>  
>   axisBuiltOnRaw=
>   
>   axisUserAgent=
>  
>   builtOn=
> ```

5. Add updated file to axis.jar\org\apache\axis\i18n\

Works on axis 1.4
Result:

State before:

[image: State before]

State after:

[image: State after]